# Android Studio build Errors

Tags: android

I have been trying allot to fix this problem. I cant figure out what to do, i get stuck on the following output error when i want to debug the project.

```
Execution failed for task ':inspectoratecalculator:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
C:\Users\FlikFlak\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4.2\dx.bat --dex --output 
C:\Users\FlikFlak\AndroidStudioProjects\Inspectorate\inspectoratecalculator\build\dex\debug
C:\Users\FlikFlak\AndroidStudioProjects\Inspectorate\inspectoratecalculator\build\classes\debug 
C:\Users\FlikFlak\AndroidStudioProjects\Inspectorate\inspectoratecalculator\build\dependency-cache\debug 
C:\Users\FlikFlak\AndroidStudioProjects\Inspectorate\inspectoratecalculator\build\pre-dexed\debug\android-support-v4-9fdb020c999e0f186e4aef883e8a4b8676e1e3ac.jar 
C:\Users\FlikFlak\AndroidStudioProjects\Inspectorate\inspectoratecalculator\build\pre-dexed\debug\classes-3cbf09a1ad548c6398f541ca3aae99491954a4cd.jar 
C:\Users\FlikFlak\AndroidStudioProjects\Inspectorate\inspectoratecalculator\build\pre-dexed\debug\support-v4-19.1.0-ce3af6ab4e02f6c952693d6706242484504a4302.jar

Error Code:
    2
Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:552)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:533)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
```

**-------------------------------------BUILD.GRADLE-----------------------------------**

```
    apply plugin: 'android'

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'

compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

Comment: Post your build.gradle file for your app module.

Comment: Whenever you use the android support library, dont include it as a JAR, but in Module Preferences > dependencies > libraries select "Android Support Library"

Comment: I have added built.gradle in above. I have already tried to add some codes to it and tried removing some, but didnt worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the v4 JAR file from your project/module jar directory as @rupps mentioned.  Also remove your "excludes" piece from the configuration.  Because you're using the the appcompat-v7 dependency, you will automatically pick up the v4 support library via Maven.

Answer (score 0):

This may occur because your have same jar referenced during building of project multiple time , may be that jar is already included some other module or library module.double check and make sure that this condition does not exist.

We have faced this kind of problem earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you have same issue with me, but my issue is I use a JDK 1.8 to compile the code, which not supported by android `dx` tools.

The fix is change the SDK path from 1.8 to a 1.7 JDK in Project's `Module Settings`.

Reference this for detail config in Mac: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24680375/1043032