# Android Studio needs JDK 7 for Android-L mac

Tags: java, android, macos, android-studio

I was trying to look how my app looks in material design and I would like to use the new cards lib.
My Problem is, that it's giving me this error within my gradle file and I need to fix that.

```
Error:compileSdkVersion android-L requires compiling with JDK 7
```

I downloaded `jdk-7u60-macosx-x64.dmg`and installed it. `java -version`in Terminal is showing me that 1.7 is installed:

```
java version "1.7.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_60-b19)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.60-b09, mixed mode)
```

well

```
ls -l `which java`
```

is giving me:

```
/usr/bin/java -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java
```

`.../current/...` doesn't have a `.../home`. I found the `.../home` here:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home
```

And set the path to the "SDK location" Preferences in Android Studio under "JDK location". But it's not working -- it seems that it still can't find JDK 7.

I'm using Mac OSX 10.9.3 and Android Studio (Beta) 0.8.1.

Comment: Do you have any specific compiler settings that say to use Java 6? (there's some Eclipse settings like this, not sure about Studio)

Answer (score 224, accepted):

Setting the directory to:
`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home`
in JDK settings solved my issue. I had the same problem getting started up.

Comment: Awesome thanks! Old JDK directory was pointing at System/Library/Java etc. They have changed the install path or something! Great help.

Comment: This worked for me as well (after downloading JDK 7).

Comment: But how to set the directory to :/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home? where is the JDK settings?

Comment: The folder name changed and now the folder name is jdk1.7.0_65.jdk :)

Comment: how to do this in windows ?

Comment: I can't figure this one out. It doesn't seem to want to change for me, when I write in the new idk location it recognizes it as not existing (but I definitely have it installed!) ugh

Comment: Important detail: old directory is /System/Library new dir is /Library

Comment: Thanks ..i was looking in /System/Library instead of /Library..Thanks for your help

Comment: latest /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_70.jdk/Contents/Home

Answer (score 204):

@megapoff answer is correct . But I face little difficulty to fix it . So here is the detail solution step-by-step

**For Mac**

1. Download the DMG file of JDK-7  [from here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html)
2. Click on DMG and follow the instructions . It will install and configure JDK-7 on mac .
3. Now in your android studio go to File->Project Structure -> SDK Location .
4. In **JDK location** click on browse and go to `/->Library->Java->JavaVirtualMachines->jdk1.7.0_60.jdk->Contents->Home`

   Note :- Its Not `/System/Library` it's `/Library`
5. click Apply and OK ....
   Bingo ..... Build the project again .....

Comment: For OS X 10.10 (Yosemite), had to use JDK 8u20 Early Access Release. You can download it [here](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html). The JDK location will be `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home`

Comment: This is what worked for me. I was looking in /System/Library and not just /Library.

Comment: Thank you veryyy muuuch!. This:  Note :- Its Not /System/Library it's /Library made my day!

Comment: Good site about this issue -> http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration/osx-jdk

Comment: Thanks ..i was looking in /System/Library instead of /Library..Thanks for your help

Answer (score 15):

The other answers are very correct but I want to be more concise and clear. To prevent others from visiting this page multiple times unnecessarily.

Important* Old Path is /System/Library/Java... and New Path is /Library/Java... (Not under the System directory)

Replace old path: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.6.0_0.jdk/Contents/Home

Set your new path: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home

Answer (score 5):

I haven't moved over to Android Studio, yet. I've used it for a few tests and really like it. Just haven't been able to switch over yet. I've had this sort of issue in Eclipse and that's obviously a different solution, but looking through one of my test projects, this appears to be how you go about it:

Open your project and go to File->Settings.

Under the Project Settings, expand Compiler and go to the Java Compiler option. You want to use javac and set the project bytecode version to 1.7.

Hopefully that'll do it.

Answer (score 0):

For jdk-7u79-macosx-x64.dmg just Setting the directory to
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home

Not in 
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home

Both are different

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looking for the folder inside :
**`/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`**

[image]

We have to look into :

**`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`**

[image]