# AndroidStudio new project error

Tags: android, android-studio

I've decided to give Android Studio a try - a long overdue.

I'm running on Mac OSX, and I've installed android studio - it starts up normally.

---

**Problem 1**

I start a new project with an empty activity. and on the top window I get a message

> Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly.

and I have 3 options: Try Again, Open Event Log, Show Log in Finder.

Try again results in the same error, and the log shows nothing useful.

---

**Problem 2**

I see the following error in the bottom window:

> Error:compileSdkVersion android-L requires compiling with JDK 7
>   Open SDK Settings
> Open File

I've checked the SKD Setting and they seems fine and points to existing paths.

---

What am I doing wrong? I'm guessing that Android Studio will just keep on getting more popular against Eclipse with android sdk.

**Edit**

When I try to run the project on the device I get the following error:

> Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]

Comment: P1. Show the log and post the error.
P2. You need JDK (java development kit) 7, nothing to do with the SDK

Comment: First wait for gradle files to download 50mb, it takes some time on creating a project. Problem number two update java dev kit to latest version, and make super you select right directory od your JDK, it will probably point out to old jdk files. Reopen android studio and it should work.

Comment: [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]. What is you minSdk?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti doesn't matter which one I set... still getting that error.

Comment: @developer82 It is not so true. Are you using Android-L? if yes, post your build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

I think that this question [was already answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472020/android-studio-needs-jdk-7-for-android-l-mac)

> Setting the directory to: **/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home** in JDK settings solved my issue. I had the same problem getting started up. Hope this helps!

Comment: That made the Gradle error disappear - but still can't compile to device.

Comment: Your device should be running the version of Android that is specified by your minsdk parameter in build.gradle. If you are trying to run Android L or kitkat project on a device running jellybean you will see this error.