# source value 1.5 is obsolete

Tags: android, android-studio

I've just switched to Android Studio from Eclipse and am getting this warning during builds. However, I don't have any idea what it means. V1.5 of what? There's definitely not enough info that I can find to pinpoint a specific point in the code (if that's what it is).

I might mention that this is an old project that goes back to Android 2.x days, but currently targets only V4.x+ and has a min-sdk of 14.

Comment: You should be targeting Java 7.

Comment: Thanks, but where is that specified? How do I change it?

Comment: There are so many duplicate questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472020/android-studio-needs-jdk-7-for-android-l-mac

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out with help from above comments: had to install the Java 1.7 JDK and then change Project Structure settings to point to that directory.