# Error:compileSdkVersion android-21 requires compiling with JDK 7 - windows

Tags: android, android-studio, android-5.0-lollipop

Android studio - 
updated sdk with android 21 , updated java to 1.7.0 . Whenever i try to compile with android L ( 21 ) , it throws this error and gradle sync is failed.

C:\Users\me>java -version
java version "1.7.0_71"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.71-b01, mixed mode)

found similar question for mac -
[Android Studio needs JDK 7 for Android-L mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472020/android-studio-needs-jdk-7-for-android-l-mac)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two options, you can just switch your compiled version back to 20 if you do not want all the goodness of SDK 21. To upgrade to JDK 7 for Windows, do this:

1. Download the Jave 7 exe from
   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html
2. Perform a straight forward install and take note of the installation folder such as C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71
3. Then click on File > Project Structure and point the JDK location to
   the location of the JDK you just installed[image]

Comment: In Ubuntu 14.04 a valid path for "JDK location" is "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64". I say "a valid path" because you can find simlinks to the same location that probably work too. I don't sure about Oracle JDK path.