# How to install android SDK platform L

Tags: android, sdk

When I open android SDK manager I see that there is no option to install android SDK platform L. I have tried just about every solution that I read on here, but nothing helped...

[image]

Comment: is there option of Android 5.0 ? or you sepcifcally lookking for L preview?

Comment: I have installed android 5.0, but android studio gives me error that I haven't installed platform L

Comment: show me manifest plz

Comment: Sounds like you might be using an older version of Android Studio or the Build tools. Double check that everything in the SDK manager is update and what version of Android Studio are you using although from the screenshot it doesn't look like you have Lollipop shown at all, although it is quite a small text so I might just not be seeing

Comment: Actually, I just wanted to start android development so every version is latest since I downloaded everything from scratch today. java JDK is 1.8.0_25.

Comment: I have installed both java jdk 7 and 8 + android studio is v0.8.14 (october 2014). If android development is as hard as "simple" installation process then I don't know if I am smart enough to continue :)

Answer (score 0):

Platform L requires JDK 7 to be installed. check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472020/android-studio-needs-jdk-7-for-android-l-mac). Install JDK 7 and then open SDK manager.You will have android L.